# How to clear a listbox of all items programatically in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, listbox

I am trying to clear a listbox in a function that resets and disables the fields on a form.

All the forums I have checked said to use:

```
    listBox.Items.Clear();
```

However this throws an exception which says:

'Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.'

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Seems you have assigned or bound the ItemsSource property. Clear the source collection.

Comment: This can be easily done by clearing the source such as

            ObservableCollection<string> src = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            
            src.Clear();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to bind the ItemsSource property of the listbox to some collection. Just clear the content of the collection. If it's an ObservableCollection, the listbox will be cleared automatically, otherwise implement the INotifyPropertyChanged pattern.

Declare the list you are binding to like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyType> ListboxItems { get; set; }
```

Then you can clear the list with

```
ListBoxItems.Clear();
```